# How to originate phone calls from Rails application using Adhearsion?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, voip, worker, adhearsion

I am using Ruby on Rails and Adhearsion. I have created both applications as stated in documentation provided on Adhearsion's website. I have workers running in background, from which I want to originate a phone call how should I achieve that ?

I am using :

`Adhearsion::OutboundCall.originate 'SIP/channel_name/0018008001300', from: "<sip:1111@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx>"`

which is working fine in `ahn` console, how should I give use it in my worker ?

I searched and I have found results and solutions for older versions of Adhearsion.

Comment: What do you mean by worker? Like a Resque/Sidekiq worker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DRb did the job, using `adhearsion-drb` gem in Adhearsion app which is on [github](https://github.com/adhearsion/adhearsion-drb).